# JSON parsing with PHP failed

Tags: php, json

How do you parse this json:

```
a:1:{i:3;a:3:{s:8:"routtype";s:9:"Alpha SS7";s:6:"credit";d:4532.600000000000363797880709171295166015625;s:8:"validity";s:3:"276";}}
```

to php object or array?

Tried this:

```
$json = 'a:1:{i:3;a:3:{s:8:"routtype";s:9:"Alpha SS7";s:6:"credit";d:4532.600000000000363797880709171295166015625;s:8:"validity";s:3:"276";}}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj);
```

with nothing printed.

Comment: Check it out at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a JSON string, but a php serialized array. Use http://php.net/unserialize to get what you want.